# Kata: Natural Sort

Tags: unit-testing, f#

I am choosing to learn F# for my own enjoyment. I am getting to the point where concepts of F# seem to be pretty easy, but understanding some of the whys and whens is a bit harder.

Before I get into the code and the explanation, let me put my question up front. I am asking where can I find better advice on formatting F# code for readability? Or can someone give me a few guiding tips based off of the example given below?

So what are the best practices for code format and file layout?

Now to the explanation of the code.

I have started practicing coding Kata's in F# just to allow me to flex the language a little.  The following program is an implementation of a [natural sort](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html). This was my first attempt to solving the problem in a TDD fashion in F#, as such I chose to forgo any framework as I did not want to deal with figuring out how to use any of them and not break the functional paradigm.

So the code below carries a light weight unit test framework.

Here is the code for the natural sort:

```
namespace Katas
    open System.Linq

    module NaturalSortKata =
        exception InvalidException of string

        type Comparison =
        | Equal
        | Lesser
        | Greater
            static member Compare x y =
                if x = y then
                    Equal
                elif x > y then
                    Greater
                else
                    Lesser

        type ChunckType =
        | NumberType
        | StringType
        | Unknown
            static member GetType (c : char) =
                if System.Char.IsDigit(c) then
                    NumberType
                else
                    StringType

            member this.Compare other = 
                match other with
                | ty when ty = this -> Equal
                | Unknown -> Lesser
                | NumberType when this = Unknown -> Greater
                | NumberType -> Lesser
                | StringType -> Greater

        let natualCompare (left : string) (right : string) = 
            if left = right then
                Equal
            else
                let fix str =
                    new System.String( str |> List.rev |> List.toArray )

                let gatherChunck str = 
                    let rec gather str acc =
                        match str with
                        | [] ->
                            let (ty, l) = acc
                            (ty, fix(l))
                        | fistLetter::rest ->
                            match acc with
                            | (ty, _) when ty = Unknown ->
                                let t = ChunckType.GetType(fistLetter)
                                gather rest (t, fistLetter :: [])
                            | (ty, l) when ty = ChunckType.GetType(fistLetter) ->
                                gather rest (ty, fistLetter::l)
                            | (ty, l) -> (ty, fix(l))

                    gather str (Unknown, [])

                let rec compare (left : string) (right : string) =
                    if (not (left.Any())) || (not (right.Any())) then
                        match left.Length, right.Length with
                        | llen, rlen when llen = rlen -> Equal
                        | llen, rlen when llen > rlen -> Greater
                        | llen, rlen when llen < rlen -> Lesser
                        | _ -> raise (InvalidException "Bad Data")
                    else
                        let lt, lChunk = left |> Seq.toList |> gatherChunck 
                        let rt, rChunk = right |> Seq.toList |> gatherChunck

                        match lt.Compare rt with
                        | Equal ->
                            if lChunk = rChunk then
                                let lVal = left.Replace(lChunk, "")
                                let rVal = right.Replace(rChunk, "")

                                compare lVal rVal
                            else
                                match lt with
                                | NumberType ->
                                    Comparison.Compare (System.Int64.Parse(lChunk)) (System.Int64.Parse(rChunk))
                                | _ ->
                                    Comparison.Compare lChunk rChunk
                        | _ ->
                            lt.Compare(rt)

                compare left right
```

Here is the code for the tests:

```
namespace Katas.Testing
    open Katas.NaturalSortKata

    module Tests =
        let test left right expected title=
            let testRun x =  
                let result = right |> natualCompare left
                if result = expected then
                    x |> printfn "%d good"
                    true
                else
                    title + " fails" |> printfn "%d %s" x
                    result 
                    |> sprintf "%d            Actual: %A" x 
                    |> sprintf "%d            Expected: %A\r\n%s" x expected
                    |> printfn "%s"
                    false

            testRun

        let testRunner tests=
            let rec runner x result tests =
                match tests with
                | [] -> result
                | head::tests -> 
                    let current = (head x) && result
                    tests |> runner (x + 1) current

            tests |> runner 1 true

        let test01 = "Simple Equality"                           |> test "one"               "one"               Equal
        let test02 = "left < right"                              |> test "left"              "right"             Lesser
        let test03 = "beta > alpha"                              |> test "beta"              "alpha"             Greater
        let test04 = "\"9\" < \"10\""                            |> test "9"                 "10"                Lesser
        let test05 = "\"alpha9\" < \"alpha10\""                  |> test "alpha9"            "alpha10"           Lesser
        let test06 = "\"alpha9Centary9\" < \"alpha9Centary10\""  |> test "alpha9Centary9"    "alpha9Centary10"   Lesser
        let test07 = "\"10\" > \"9\""                            |> test "10"                 "9"                Greater
        let test08 = "\"alpha10\" > \"alpha9\""                  |> test "alpha10"            "alpha9"           Greater
        let test09 = "\"alpha9Centary9\" < \"alpha9Centary10\""  |> test "alpha9Centary10"    "alpha9Centary9"   Greater

        let tests = test01 :: test02 :: test03 :: test04 :: test05 :: test06 :: test07 :: test08 :: test09 ::[]


        let runTests =        
            tests |> testRunner |> printfn "%b"
```

Here is the code that runs it all:

```
open Katas.NaturalSortKata
open Katas.Testing.Tests

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    //Katas.Lockers.showLockerResults 300
    runTests
    let _ = System.Console.ReadKey(true)
    1
```

Comment: BTW, I believe the idiomatic way of ignoring the result of something is `System.Console.ReadKey(true) |> ignore`, not declaring an unused local. Also, I think you don't even need to declare `main`, you can put the code directly at the top level of the file.

Comment: Also, “chunck” is a typo, the correct spelling is “chunk”.

Comment: I did not know about ignore. Thank you. I started learning functional programming through Erlang, which an underscore is an ignore. I assumed that it would be the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code formatting is very readable. The minor issue is that you don't have to indent after `namespace` declaration. I would choose to open module directly to save a level of indentation (see attached code later).

> So what are the best practices for code format and file layout?

I think [F# code formatting guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233191.aspx) have very concrete suggestions on these issues.

There are a few small problems with your code:

1. In `naturalCompare`, you should move local functions to the top so the logic of the function is clear.
2. In `compare`, if you remove `when` in the last clause, you don't have to superficially throw an exception.
3. Value `tests` is more readable in the form of normal list declaration.

   ```
   let tests = [ test01; test02; test03; test04; test05; test06; test07; test08; test09; ]
   ```

Here is reformatted version of `Katas.NaturalSortKata` module. You could do the same for `Katas.Testing.Tests`.

```
// 0) Declare module to save a level of indentation
module Katas.NaturalSortKata

open System.Linq

type Comparison =
| Equal
| Lesser
| Greater
    static member Compare x y =
        if x = y then
            Equal
        elif x > y then
            Greater
        else
            Lesser

type ChunckType =
| NumberType
| StringType
| Unknown
    static member GetType (c : char) =
        if System.Char.IsDigit(c) then
            NumberType
        else
            StringType

    member this.Compare other = 
        match other with
        | ty when ty = this -> Equal
        | Unknown -> Lesser
        | NumberType when this = Unknown -> Greater
        | NumberType -> Lesser
        | StringType -> Greater

let naturalCompare (left : string) (right : string) = 
    // 1) Move local functions on top
    let fix str =
        new System.String( str |> List.rev |> List.toArray )

    let gatherChunck str = 
        let rec gather str acc =
            match str with
            | [] ->
                let (ty, l) = acc
                (ty, fix(l))
            | fistLetter::rest ->
                match acc with
                | (ty, _) when ty = Unknown ->
                    let t = ChunckType.GetType(fistLetter)
                    gather rest (t, fistLetter :: [])
                | (ty, l) when ty = ChunckType.GetType(fistLetter) ->
                    gather rest (ty, fistLetter::l)
                | (ty, l) -> (ty, fix(l))

        gather str (Unknown, [])

    let rec compare (left : string) (right : string) =
        if (not (left.Any())) || (not (right.Any())) then
            match left.Length, right.Length with
            | llen, rlen when llen = rlen -> Equal
            | llen, rlen when llen > rlen -> Greater
            | llen, rlen -> Lesser // 2) Remove superficial when guard
        else
            let lt, lChunk = left |> Seq.toList |> gatherChunck 
            let rt, rChunk = right |> Seq.toList |> gatherChunck

            match lt.Compare rt with
            | Equal ->
                if lChunk = rChunk then
                    let lVal = left.Replace(lChunk, "")
                    let rVal = right.Replace(rChunk, "")

                    compare lVal rVal
                else
                    match lt with
                    | NumberType ->
                        Comparison.Compare (System.Int64.Parse(lChunk)) (System.Int64.Parse(rChunk))
                    | _ ->
                        Comparison.Compare lChunk rChunk
            | _ ->
                lt.Compare(rt)

    if left = right then
        Equal
    else
        compare left right
```

**UPDATE:**

After answering your question, I started developing a source code formatter for F#. More information can be found [on Gihub](https://github.com/dungpa/fantomas).

Results from the tool or [its companion formatting guideline](https://github.com/dungpa/fantomas/blob/master/docs/FormattingConventions.md) can give you some hints for good formatting.

Comment: Thank you, the link is great, and the advice you give makes since.